# R programming , reading csv file

Tags: r

```
Sample1<-read.csv(paste0(filename,".csv"),header=T,stringAsFactors=F)
```

My question is I want to extract specific rows and columns out of 100000 records 
Also what is the use of paste0() function here

Comment: Specific? Characterized by some particular value or something? Provide some example please.

Comment: For example i want to read out of my csv file that contains records for hospital claims i want to read on the "names "column and "claims" column

Comment: It's better to read whole file than extract specific data, as it's shown in answer below, here it is how `paste` function works.`paste("some_string", 1, "@%#%@")` making one string, result: `[1] "some_string 1 @%#%@"`

Answer (score 2):

paste0() is used to add strings together. In your example, the filename and .csv are made one.

As for selecting specific rows. You don't do that with read.csv. You do that after. For example, this selects the first, third and sixt row from the second and fourth column.

```
Sample1[c(1,3,6),c(2,4)]
```

This is 100% a duplicate question. I don't know how to flag it.

Comment: Thank you that i understood well the function and use of paste0() , i am not able to get why it is used in this manner or say why it is used with read.csv and what would happen in case i dont use it . Thanks